# Dynamic video/image styling using css or html

Tags: html, css, embed

I can embed a YouTube video clip in my HTML page as so;

```
<div class="videob">    
        <iframe title="YouTube video player" 
        class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 
        width="610" height="390" src=
        "http://www.youtube.com/embed/grh03-NjHzc"
        frameborder="0" allowFullScreen>
        </iframe>
</div>
```

I apologize if I come across as vague but what I actually want is for the clip to come to the center of the page when clicked and for the background to be dimmed. Similar to what the "Turn Off The Lights" app does in Google chrome. I'd like to do the same for images.

Comment: The center of what? parent page? iframe?

Comment: This isn't doable with just CSS. You need to make a hidden background-bg div which has a fixed position and covers the whole page, give it black background and some opacity. Then you can display it and the videob div with javascript once video is clicked. Alternatively you can create the background div with javascript. The videob div also needs to have fixed (or absolute) position and you need to give it left: 50%; and margin-left: -(element width / 2) to position it in the center of the screen. Hopefully that will get you started.

Comment: You can use a lightbox-script, such as [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/blog#tip4) (there is a YouTube example on their website) and display the video inside that lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Shadowbox, as Fancybox tends to cause IE to freeze. You can check it out here

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

So after you setup shadowbox...

Here's the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>
```

Here's your video:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/grh03-NjHzc" rel="shadowbox;width=610;height=390;" title="Nelson Mandela's inaugural address">
```

Cheers!